# Declare Cells(row,col) using variables from ARRAY

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Is it possible to to declare Cell position with using variables from an array?

Here is my old code which works perfectly but what if I need many more Cells? (I make it shorter). This code by pressing button sets Value of selected cells to zero.

```
Sub ResetButt01_Click()

Cells(12, 5).Value = 0
Cells(12, 13).Value = 0
Cells(12, 21).Value = 0
Cells(19, 4).Value = 0
Cells(19, 6).Value = 0
Cells(19, 12).Value = 0

End Sub
```

And here is my attempt to do it by using Array:

```
Sub ResetButt01_Click()

Dim myRow() As Variant
Dim myCol() As Variant

myRow = Array(12, 12, 12, 19, 19, 19)
myCol = Array(5, 13, 21, 4, 6, 12)

Cells(myRow, myCol).Value = 0

End Sub
```

But this code doesn't work. So I tried this:

```
Sub ResetButt01_Click()

Dim myRow() As Variant
Dim myCol() As Variant
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

myRow = Array(12, 12, 12, 19, 19, 19)
myCol = Array(5, 13, 21, 4, 6, 12)

r = myRow
c = myCol

Cells(r, c).Value = 0

End Sub
```

But again it doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to put values to array and this use these values as variables to define the position of Cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array approach you have used is actually much slower than writing to the range, as you are writing to each indvidual cell

You would be better off defining a range, and writing to it in a sigle shot, code is also easier to read. On my testing this is 4x faster than the answer you have selected.

```
Sub ResetButt02_Click()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("E12,M12,U12,D19,E19,l19")
rng1.Value2 = vbNullString
End Sub
```

*update*

When setting a single range there is a limit of 255 characters. Either work with two ranges as you did, or use `Union` to mesh the two ranges together:

```
Sub ResetButt01_Kliknút()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("C33,C40,C67,C74,C88,C95,D19,D53,E12,E26,E33,E40,E47,E60,E67,E74,E81,E88,E95,E102,F19,F53,G33,G40")
Set rng2 = Range("G67,G74,G88,G95,K53,K60,L19,L26,L88,M12,M33,M40,M47,M53,M60,M67,M74,M81,M95,M102,N19,N26,N88,O53,O60,T26,T33,T67,T74,T81,T88,U12,U19,U40,U47,U53,U60,U95,U102,V26,V33,V67,V74,V81,V88")
Set rng2 = Union(rng1, rng2)
rng2.Value2 = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ... you are right it is faster without ARRAY but when I create one range it doesnt work - there was error. I try it several times and nothing. Then all I do was create second Dim rng2 As Range and I pul one half of cells to first range rng1 and second half of cells to another range rng2 and then it works perfectly. It seems to me that thare is limitation if you want fill range with single difrent cells like Range("A3, B3, C7, D1, D5.... etc).

Comment: @beaster can you pls add your example above?

Comment: This is my new code:   `Sub ResetButt01_Kliknúť()  

    Dim rng1 As Range  
    Dim rng2 As Range  

    Set rng1 = Range("C33,C40,C67,C74,C88,C95,D19,D53,E12,E26,E33,E40,E47,E60,E67,E74,E81,E88,E95,E102,F19,F53,G33,G40")  
    Set rng2 = Range("G67,G74,G88,G95,K53,K60,L19,L26,L88,M12,M33,M40,M47,M53,M60,M67,M74,M81,M95,M102,N19,N26,N88,O53,O60,T26,T33,T67,T74,T81,T88,U12,U19,U40,U47,U53,U60,U95,U102,V26,V33,V67,V74,V81,V88")  
    rng1.Value2 = 0  
    rng2.Value2 = 0  

    End Sub`

Comment: Why I cant put new line to the comment?  I tried to do that with two spaces to add linebreak but it doesnt work.  I think I am big lama.

Comment: @beaster  see my update post above. For future reference its easier to edit your question - code and comments don't mix :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a comma separated string with cell addresses:

```
Const myCells As String = "A1, B2, C3, D4, E5, F6"
Range(myCells).Value = 0
```

You could also create named range `myCells2` and simply call:

```
Range("myCells2").Value = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *Arrays*

```
Sub ResetButt01_Click()

Dim myRow() As Variant
Dim myCol() As Variant
Dim i As Long, R As Long, C As Long

myRow = Array(12, 12, 12, 19, 19, 19)
myCol = Array(5, 13, 21, 4, 6, 12)

For i = 0 To 5
    R = myRow(i)
    C = myCol(i)
    Cells(R, C).Value = 0
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using cycle:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ResetButt01_Click()

Dim myRow() As Variant
Dim myCol() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

myRow = Array(12, 12, 12, 19, 19, 19)
myCol = Array(5, 13, 21, 4, 6, 12)

For i = LBound(myRow) To UBound(myRow)
    Cells(myRow(i), myCol(i)).Value = 0
Next i

End Sub
```

M.

Comment: Yeh this one also work and by your solution matro I finaly realize how it works. I am really very thankfull for your post.